# Why do I need the extra pair of curly braces when defining an array of pairs?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm sorry if this is a common question, I don't know how I'd search for it so I figured it best to just ask.

I'm wanting to define an `std::array` of `std::pair`s in C++ to store SFML `sf::IntRects` in. I messed with it for like 10 minutes and finally realized that this compiles:

```
std::array<std::pair<sf::IntRect, sf::IntRect>, 1> aliens{
    {
        {sf::IntRect{2,3,1,2}, sf::IntRect{4,1,3,2}}
    }
};
```

Why do I need the extra set of curly braces around the pair itself? When I take them away:

```
std::array<std::pair<sf::IntRect, sf::IntRect>, 1> aliens{
    {sf::IntRect{2,3,1,2}, sf::IntRect{4,1,3,2}}
};
```

I get an error `No suitable user-defined conversion from "sf::IntRect" to "std::pair<sf::IntRect,sf::IntRect>" exists`

What are these curly braces doing? I can't imagine what they'd be needed for.

Comment: Because `std::array` wraps a raw array inside, that is `_M_instance[_Nm]`, the `{}` inside `{{}}` initializes the `_M_instance`, and the external `{}` initializes `std::array`.

Comment: An `std::array` cannot be initialised with the value of a single element (which would be the meaning if only a single `{}` was allowed). Aggregate initialisation of a single `std::pair<sf:IntRect, sf::IntRect>` requires a `{}`.  Aggregate initialisation of an `std::array` requires a pair of `{}` surrounding a set of initialisers for the elements (separated by commas if there is more than one).  Since the  initialiser of each element is surrounded by a `{}`, the "extra" set of `{}` is required (the inner pair(s) for initialising the element(s), the outer pair for initialising the array).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a wrapper template around built-in C-style array. You may think of it as something like

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class array {
  T arr[N];
  ...
};
```

Both `std::array` and built-in C-style array are aggregate types. You initialize it using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) syntax. It would be something like

```
std::array<T, N> array = {{ t0, t1, t2 }};
```

The outer `{}` is for `std::array` itself while the inner `{}` is for the wrapped built-in C-style array.

Look at your example

```
std::array<std::pair<sf::IntRect, sf::IntRect>, 1> aliens{
    {sf::IntRect{2,3,1,2}, sf::IntRect{4,1,3,2}}
};
```

The error is more obvious when reformated as below.

```
std::array<std::pair<sf::IntRect, sf::IntRect>, 1> aliens{{
  sf::IntRect{2,3,1,2},
  sf::IntRect{4,1,3,2}
}};
```

You are trying to initialize a pair with a single `sf::IntRect` object.